# Thinking in Clojure: Avoid OOP for simple string parser

Tags: parsing, clojure, functional-programming, atomic

I'm currently implementing a small parser in Clojure that takes an input string like:

> aaa (bbb(ccc)ddd(eee)) fff (ggg) hhh

and returns the string without characters that are not in brackets, i.e.

> (bbb(ccc)ddd(eee))(ggg)

I've written the following function:

```
(defn- parse-str [input]
  (let [bracket (atom 0)
        output (atom [])]
     (doseq [ch (seq input)]
         (case ch
          \( (swap! bracket inc)
          \) (swap! bracket dec)
           nil)
         (if (or (> @bracket 0) (= ch \)))
           (swap! output conj ch))) 
    (apply str @output)))
```

which works for me:

> (parse-str "aaa (bbb(ccc)ddd(eee)) fff (ggg) hhh")
>
> "(bbb(ccc)ddd(eee))(ggg)"

I am however concerned that my approach is a too object oriented since it uses atoms as some kind of local variables to keep the current state of the parser.

Is it possible to write the same function from a more functional programming perspective? (avoiding the atoms?)

Any comments to improve my code are appreciated as well.

Comment: Take a look at parser combinators, there are many Parsec-like implementations available for Clojure. This approach is as functional as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways: You can use explicit recursion or reduce.

```
(defn parse-str [input]
  (letfn [(parse [input bracket result]
            (if (seq input)
              (let [[ch & rest] input]
                (case ch
                  \( (recur rest (inc bracket) (conj result ch))
                  \) (recur rest (dec bracket) (conj result ch))
                  (recur rest bracket (if (> bracket 0)
                                        (conj result ch)
                                        result))))
              result))]
    (clojure.string/join (parse input 0 []))))


(defn parse-str [input]
  (clojure.string/join
   (second (reduce (fn [acc ch]
                     (let [[bracket result] acc]
                       (case ch
                         \( [(inc bracket) (conj result ch)]
                         \) [(dec bracket) (conj result ch)]
                         [bracket (if (> bracket 0)
                                    (conj result ch)
                                    result)])))
                   [0 []]
                   input))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of cases where you would use local variables, you just put any variable that changes as a parameter to loop, thereby using recursion instead of mutation.

```
(defn- parse-str [input]
  ;; Instead of using atoms to hold the state, use parameters in loop
  (loop [output []
         bracket 0
         ;; The [ch & tail] syntax is called destructuring,
         ;; it means let ch be the first element of (seq input),
         ;; and tail the rest of the elements
         [ch & tail] (seq input)] 
    ;; If there's no elements left, ch will be nil, which is logical false
    (if ch
      (let [bracket* (case ch
                       \( (inc bracket)
                       \) (dec bracket)
                       bracket)
            output* (if (or (> bracket* 0) (= ch \)))
                      (conj output ch)
                      output)]
        ;; Recurse with the updated values
        (recur output* bracket* tail))
      ;; If there's no characters left, apply str to the output
      (apply str output))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an iterative version of your function; but it's still functionally pure. I find having the code laid out like this makes it easy to read. Remember, when using recursion, always check your termination condition first.

```
(defn parse-str [s]
  (loop [[x & xs] (seq s), acc [], depth 0]
    (cond
      (not x)      (clojure.string/join acc)
      (= x \()     (recur xs (conj acc x) (inc depth))
      (= x \))     (recur xs (conj acc x) (dec depth))
      (<= depth 0) (recur xs acc depth)
      :else        (recur xs (conj acc x) depth))))
```